# Некорректное чтение условий в цикле while

Tags: c++, visual-studio, while, логические-выражения

```
while ((x > -1) && ((urav[x] != '+') || (urav[x] != '-'))) 
while ((x > -1) && !((urav[x] == '+') || (urav[x] == '-')))
```

В первой строчке условие после `&&` полностью игнорируется, в при вынесении `!` за скобку, как во второй строчке, оно учитывается. Кто знает, в чем причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте сообразим...

```
(urav[x] != '+') || (urav[x] != '-')
```

Если `urav[x]` - `+`, мы получаем `false||true == true`.
Если `urav[x]` - `-`, мы получаем `true||false == true`.
Если `urav[x]` - что-то еще, получаем `true||true==true`.

Т.е. это **всегда** `true`. Условие `&&true` - это просто первая часть условия.

Вот оптимизатор и выбросил лишнее.

Надеюсь, то, что `!a || !b` совсем не то же, что и `!(a||b)`, для вас очевидно? Т.е. что условие во втором цикле *отличается* от условия в первом цикле?

На всякий случай: `!a || !b` по-другому записывается как `!(a&&b)`.
А `!(a||b)` - как `(!a && !b)`...

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаем, что второе условие - исходное, а первое - то что у вас получилось после внесения отрицания в скобки. Но внесение отрицания в скобки вы не правильно выполнили, тут нужно применять [законы де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), т.е. при внесении/вынесении отрицания логическое ИЛИ (дизъюнкция) должно меняться на И (конъюнкция), и наоборот:

```
!(urav[x] == '+' || urav[x] == '-') <=> (эквивалентно) (urav[x] != '+' && urav[x] != '-')
```

(убрал лишние скобки, т.к. операции сравнения и так имеют более высокий приоритет, чем логические операции)

Если в первом выражении, наоборот, вынести отрицание за скобки, то получим:

```
!(urav[x] == '+' && urav[x] == '-')
```

Выражение в скобках всегда ложно, т.к. значение в ячейке массива не может одновременно быть равно двум значениям, применяем отрицание - получается `true`. Т.е., независимо от конкретного значения в ячейке массива данное условие всегда даст вам `true`.